# Isotope 3 Column Layout

Tags: jquery, masonry, jquery-isotope

I've tried a few solutions but just can't seem to make this work. I'm trying to create a 3 column layout with Isotope using the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.feed').isotope({
        itemSelector : '.card',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 200
        }
    });
})
```

The following CSS:

```
.feed .card
{
  border-radius:4px;
  margin: 5px;
  float:left;
  width:33.3%;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, it puts the items into columns but does not space them evenly into 3 columns to make full use of the parent container width?